# Why are 'id' and 'is' behaving differently in Python methods vs static methods?

Tags: python, identity, equality

```
class A:
     def self_method(self):
         pass

     @staticmethod
     def static_method():
         pass


a1, a2 = A(), A()

print(a1.self_method == a2.self_method,
      id(a1.self_method) == id(a2.self_method),
      a1.self_method is a2.self_method)

print(a1.static_method == a2.static_method,
      id(a1.static_method) == id(a2.static_method),
      a1.static_method is a2.static_method)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> (False, True, False)
> (True, True, True)
> ```

Why is `id(a1.self_method) == id(a2.self_method)` `True`, but `a1.self_method is a2.self_method` is `False`? What does it mean? Does python recreate this method/s for every object or not?

Comment: @DeepSpace How does your suggested duplicate address the difference between `id(...) == id(...)` and `is` here? One of the answers even says "`a is b` is the same as `id(a) == id(b)`", which is apparently not true in this case.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?  The omission of `object` in the class suggests Python 3, but the output of tuples from the prints suggests Python 2.